# clang: error: no such file or directory: 'DDEBUG'

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.6

I want to use `ALog()` and `DLog()` instead of `NSLog()`. Hence, I followed the instructions given  on this [link](http://www.cimgf.com/2009/01/24/dropping-nslog-in-release-builds/).
Following the instructions, I added `DDEBUG` to my `OTHER C FLAGS` in my target. But on running it fails and gives following error.

> clang: error: no such file or directory: `'DDEBUG'`
>   Command `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang` failed with exit code 1

I also want to know that how to check whether Configuration is set to Debug (according to given link I need to check this).

Comment: [We close all the typo questions.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that you added `-DDEBUG` and not `DDEBUG`?

**EDIT**: To check that your Build Configuration is set to Debug in Xcode 4, click on the name of your app in the toolbar, where it says "Scheme":

[image]

Then click `Edit Scheme`:

[image]

And if it says `Debug` under `Run (your app).app` you're golden!

[image]

Comment: Awesome man. Thanks. That was the problem. Can you answer my question which I just added at the end?

Comment: @AkashPatel I added an explanation... Happy coding!